# Wait for button press (no text boxes, etc.)

Tags: c#

I have a code to take a screenshot, but I want it to be executed when I press the space button, how do I make it wait for me to press it?

```
Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }
    bitmap.Save("test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: Please share the code you have

Answer (score 3):

That's actually the wrong paradigm. In Windows environments, you don't wait for events; you respond to them as they occur.

Assuming for a moment that this is a WinForms application, that means you write code for the `KeyDown` event of the form itself.

Answer (score -1):

```
char input;
do
{
    input = Console.ReadKey();
} while (input != ' ')
```

Comment: This should never be done in a GUI app.  Even if it appeared to work, you're tying up the GUI thread while you wait -- making the app unresponsive.

Comment: He hadn't stated it was a GUI app when I wrote it.